# How to select top records from a table not using TOP / ROWNUM?

Tags: sql

There is TOP command. However, if we want not to use the TOP command what would be the best way of selecting top 5 records?

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM table1;
```

Comment: Are you using SQL server or another dialect? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to implement it using only SQL commands (which are common among all implementations of SQL databases). The reason is to understand how the TOP function works.

Comment: If you want to understand how `top n` works, the best place to start looking is in the query plan for a `top n` query. There's a fairly simple (but very inefficient) way to do this in standard SQL, but it is likely to be totally different to how the RDBMS would do it.

Comment: @MarkBannister "There's a fairly simple (but very inefficient) way to do this in standard SQL" and what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but very inefficient approach:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
        (select count(*)
         from table1 c
         where c.order_column <= t.order_column) top_n
 from table1 t) sq
where top_n <= 5
```